# Query set with Annotate using Concat is giving an error

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to use query set with Django, I want to have an id as month-day which I'm trying to use concat functions from django.models.function and gives me an error. My idea is basically to group by id( which month-day in string) and total cost. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
qs=queryset.annotate(id=Concat(str(ExtractMonth('start_time')),Value('/'),str(ExtractDay('start_time')))).values('id','code')\
        .annotate(total_cost=sum('total_cost'))
```

Error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'ExtractMonth(F(start_time))' into field. Choices are:x,y,z...
```

Comment: The `str(..)` is resolved at *Python* level, so you basically pass `Concat('ExtractMonth(F(start_time))', ...)` (so with strings as operands, no processing of fields.

Comment: I tried it but it gives me same error. Any other possible way to try it out. Thanks for your response.

Comment: It's probably not the same error if you followed Willem's advice. Nevertheless, usually you cannot  annotate `id`, because it conflicts with a model field. And you'll probably have to specify `Concat` output˙field. Something like this: `.annotate(ident=Concat(ExtractMonth('start_time'), Value('/'), ExtractDay('start_time'), output_field=CharField()))`

Comment: @Borut Thanks for the comment. This worked. I appreciate your time.